# Setting up NGINX to route from IP address and port to URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

What I am trying to do is route services to local URLS based on their port numbers. For example I have a gitlab server and Postgresql server running in docker on an Ubuntu server. They are accessible via host IP:port but I want to be able to specify, let's say gitlab-server/ for gitlab server and postgresql for the postgresql server. I installed nginx but I'm not sure how to set that up?

The URL's will only be accessible within my network. Any advice, suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Current Behavior:

-- xx.xx.xx.xx is the UBUNTU server so the same IP address for each service just different ports.

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4080/ -> gitlab

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5432/ -> postgresql

http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000/ -> portainer

This is what I am trying to achieve:

http://gitlab-server/ --> http://xx.xx.xx.xx:4080/

http://postgresql/ --> http://xx.xx.xx.xx:5432/

http://portainer/ --> http://xx.xx.xx.xx:9000/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `http://` scheme to access PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL has its own protocol that is not compatible with HTTP.